# merge two array with same element id

Tags: php, mysql

here is the sql:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT o.order_id, cgd.name as customer_group, CONCAT(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname) AS customer_name,
email, telephone, payment_firstname,  payment_lastname, payment_address_1, payment_address_2, payment_city, payment_zone, payment_postcode, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT op.name) as prod_name, op.model as prod_model, GROUP_CONCAT(op.quantity) as prod_quantity,
CONCAT(o.shipping_firstname, ' ', o.shipping_lastname,',',o.shipping_address_1,',',o.shipping_address_2,',', o.shipping_city,'-',o.shipping_postcode) AS shipping_address,
 o.payment_method, o.shipping_method, o.total, o.currency_code,o.currency_value,
 o.date_added, oos.name as order_status, o.custom_field as agentcode
FROM oc_order o
LEFT JOIN oc_customer_group_description cgd ON (o.customer_group_id = cgd.customer_group_id)
LEFT JOIN oc_order_product op ON (o.order_id = op.order_id)
LEFT JOIN oc_order_status oos ON (o.order_status_id = oos.order_status_id) WHERE cgd.language_id = 1 GROUP BY o.order_id";
```

I have a database with results having different array with same id

```
Array ( [order_id] => 1 [prod_name] => prod1 [qty] => 1)
Array ( [order_id] => 1 [prod_name] => prod2 [qty] => 1)
Array ( [order_id] => 2 [prod_name] => prod1 [qty] => 1)
Array ( [order_id] => 3 [prod_name] => prod1 [qty] => 1)
```

I want the above to merge as this:

```
    Array ( [order_id] => 1 [prod_name] => prod1,prod2 [qty] => 1,1)
    Array ( [order_id] => 2 [prod_name] => prod1 [qty] => 1)
    Array ( [order_id] => 3 [prod_name] => prod1 [qty] => 1)
```

After I added GROUP_CONCAT it reults in :

```
Array ( [order_id] => 1 [prod_name] => prod1,prod1,prod2,prod2 [qty] => 1,1,1,1)
    Array ( [order_id] => 2 [prod_name] => prod1 [qty] => 1)
    Array ( [order_id] => 3 [prod_name] => prod1 [qty] => 1)
```

DB Structure is:

```
o (order): 
    1   order_id    int(11) Primary Primary
op (order_product): 
    1   order_product_id    int(11) 
    2   order_id    int(11) 
    3   product_id  int(11)
    4   name    varchar(255)
    5   quantity    int(4)
    6   price   decimal(15,4)
    7   total   decimal(15,4)


cgd (customer_group_description):
   1    customer_group_id   int(11) 
    2   language_id int(11)     
    3   name    varchar(32)     
    4   description text
```

Comment: I used GROUP_CONCAT in mysql query but it give me duplicate values of prodname and qty as:  Array ( [order_id] => 1 [prod_name] => prod1,prod1,prod2,prod2 [qty] => 1,1,1,1). How to remove duplicate here

Comment: Add your SQL request to your initial post, please.

Comment: @Eiji Added please check

Comment: The probleme is you are trying to do it all in once... It should have a better way to do it but I need more time x]

Comment: @Eiji ok take your time :)

Comment: Can you confirm the structure? I have add it to my post

Comment: @Eiji its Mysql

Comment: @Eiji I had updated intial post for DB Structure

Answer (score 0):

In php you can loop to do that :

```
$merge_arr = [];

foreach( $arr as $key => $row){

    if( isset( $merge_arr[ $row['order_id'] ] ) ) {
        $merge_arr[ $row['order_id'] ][ 'order_id' ] .= "," . $arr[ $key ][ 'prod_name' ];  
        $merge_arr[ $row['order_id'] ][ 'prod_name' ] .= "," . $arr[ $key ][ 'prod_name' ];
        $merge_arr[ $row['order_id'] ][ 'qty' ] ,= "," $arr[ $row['order_id'] ][ 'qty' ];
    } else {
        $merge_arr[ $row['order_id'] ][ 'prod_name' ] = $arr[ $row['order_id'] ][ 'prod_name' ];
        $merge_arr[ $row['order_id'] ][ 'qty' ] = $arr[ $row['order_id'] ][ 'qty' ];
    }

}
```

in SQL :

```
SELECT order_id, GROUP_CONCAT(prod_name), GROUP_CONCAT(qty)
FROM your_table
GROUP_BY order_id
```

If you can, use the SQL solution, which is far more faster.

Is Your DB structure looking like that? (In a simple version)

```
o (order): 
    order_id PK
    order_status_id FK
    customer_group_id FK

op (order_product): 
    order_product_id PK
    order_id FK
    quantity

os (order_status):
    order_status_id PK

cgd (customer_group_description):
    customer_group_id PK
```

Comment: yes I used this sql but give duplicate values. please see my sql in my que

Comment: yes sort of. I had updated in my intial post.Total 3 tables are used in this sql query

Comment: Hello I Got it to some extent But still its not fully done.I had added this to my query : GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT op.name) as prod_name, GROUP_CONCAT(op.quantity) as prod_quantity. Please see my intial post for modified query. But still in case of quantity if I use DISTINCT it reults in :1 if two products have same qty ordered(say 1) and without DISTINCT it results (1,1,1,1) what can i do for quantity